# Object doesnot match SQL query results - EF Core 5

Tags: entity-framework-core

I have a `DBContext` where `PriceListTest` object is loaded as follows

`DBContext.cs`:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    //other code removed
    
    //pricelist
    modelBuilder.Entity<PriceListTest>().ToTable(null);

    modelBuilder.Entity<PriceListTest>().ToSqlQuery(
            @"SELECT T.ID, T.SHORTNAME, T.DESCRIPTION, CTL.CoCTestCode AS CODE, CTL.CoCTestName AS NAME, CTL.CLIENTID, T.ISSET, 0 AS PRICELISTID, CONT.MATRIXTYPEID AS MatrixTypeId, -1 AS MATRIXID
            FROM [TESTLIST] T
            INNER JOIN [COCTESTLIST] CTL ON ELVISTESTLISTID = T.ID
            INNER JOIN CUSTOMERCONTAINERS_TESTLIST custTest on custTest.TESTLISTID = T.ID
            INNER JOIN CUSTOMERCONTAINERS cont on cont.id = custTest.CustomerContainerID
            WHERE T.RECORDSTATUS = 0");

 
}
```

In this code, `MatrixTypeId` field is the problem!

When I run this query in SQL it will return the following result:

| ID | ClientID | MatrixTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7893 | NULL | 1 |
| 7893 | NULL | 2 |
| 7893 | NULL | 2 |
| 7891 | NULL | 1 |
| 7891 | 735 | 1 |
| 7891 | NULL | 2 |

and so on.. (total of 28 records)

In my repository, I filter it based on some parameters.

`TestListRepository`:

```
public async Task<List<PriceListTest>> Search(string text,int clientId, int batchId)
{
     // some code removed for brevity
     var productQuery = await context.PriceListTests.Where(p => !existingTestIds.Contains(p.Id) && (p.Name.Contains(text) || p.Code.Contains(text))
                    && (p.ClientId == newClientId)
                    && sampleMatrixTypes.Contains(p.MatrixTypeId)).Distinct().ToListAsync();

    // productQuery.ToQueryString();

    return productQuery;
}
```

The query that I grab from `productQuery.ToQueryString();` is:

```
DECLARE @__text_1 nvarchar(4000) = N'BTEX';

SELECT DISTINCT [p].[Id], [p].[ClientId], [p].[Code], [p].[Description], [p].[Isset], [p].[MatrixId], [p].[MatrixTypeId], [p].[Name], [p].[PRICELISTID], [p].[ShortName]
FROM 
    (SELECT T.ID, T.SHORTNAME, T.DESCRIPTION, CTL.CoCTestCode AS CODE, CTL.CoCTestName AS NAME, CTL.CLIENTID, T.ISSET, 0 AS PRICELISTID, CONT.MATRIXTYPEID AS MatrixTypeId, -1 AS MATRIXID
     FROM [TESTLIST] T
     INNER JOIN [COCTESTLIST] CTL ON ELVISTESTLISTID = T.ID
     INNER JOIN CUSTOMERCONTAINERS_TESTLIST custTest ON custTest.TESTLISTID = T.ID
     INNER JOIN CUSTOMERCONTAINERS cont on cont.id = custTest.CustomerContainerID
     WHERE T.RECORDSTATUS = 0) AS [p]
WHERE (([p].[Id] NOT IN (CAST(5233 AS smallint), CAST(5234 AS smallint), CAST(5766 AS smallint)) AND (((@__text_1 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__text_1, [p].[Name]) > 0)) OR ((@__text_1 LIKE N'') OR (CHARINDEX(@__text_1, [p].[Code]) > 0)))) AND [p].[ClientId] IS NULL) AND [p].[MatrixTypeId] IN (1, 2)
```

When I run this query, again I get the expected/correct resultset in SQL

| ID | ClientID | MatrixTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7893 | NULL | 1 |
| 7893 | NULL | 2 |
| 7891 | NULL | 1 |
| 7891 | NULL | 2 |

But when I get the json response, it has all 4 `matrixtypeid` values fixed as 1

Also, watching the object in debugger has all 4 matrixtypeId are set as 1

| ID | ClientID | MatrixTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 7893 | NULL | 1 |
| 7893 | NULL | 1 |
| 7891 | NULL | 1 |
| 7891 | NULL | 1 |

**PriceListTest.cs**

```
public class PriceListTest
{
    public short Id { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }        
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    public bool Isset { get; set; }
    public int PRICELISTID { get; set; }
    public int MatrixTypeId { get; set; }
    public int MatrixId { get; set; }
}
```

P.S: Other fields like ShortName,Description, Code, Name are all based off on ID so they are repeated as often as ID is being in the above sample.

Also, PriceListID and MatrixId are fixed for backward compatibility but are irrelevant for my code.

UPDATE: I have created a new join table to avoid nesting of so many objects. The new query is:

> SELECT distinct T.ID, T.SHORTNAME, T.DESCRIPTION, CTL.CoCTestCode, CTL.CoCTestName, CTL.CLIENTID, T.ISSET, CTLM.MATRIXTYPEID
> FROM [TESTLIST] T
> INNER JOIN [COCTESTLIST] CTL ON ELVISTESTLISTID = T.ID
> INNER JOIN [CoCTestList_MATRIXTYPE] CTLM ON ctl.ID = CTLM.COCTESTLISTID
> WHERE T.RECORDSTATUS = 0

Instead of PriceListTest I am now using CoCTestList class/table which is more relevant and straight forward. Also, I have removed the hard coded fields: MatrixID and PriceListID.

The resulting json though still is giving MatrixTypeId as 1 :)

**CoCTestList.cs**

```
public class CoCTestList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public string PriceBookSection { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] 
    public string PriceBookGroup { get; set; }
    public string CoCTestCode { get; set; }
    public string CoCTestName { get; set; }
    //[NotMapped] 
    public int ElvisTestListId { get; set; }
    public int? ClientId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] 
    public bool IsEnabled { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] 
    public string ShortName { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] 
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] 
    public bool Isset { get; set; }
    [NotMapped] 
    public int MatrixTypeId { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: `PriceListTest` class please. Plus any additional fluent configuration relevant to it.

Comment: This doesn't help. There must be something else you are omitting. Something telling EF that the `MatrixId` is unique. Relationship to `MatrixType` entity? Marked as one-to-one instead of many-to-one?

Comment: ok let me add matrix and matrixtype classes

Comment: there's no fluentAPI about matrixtype..for matrix I have added (although sample seems irrelevant)

Comment: From DB perspective a matrixtype can be used by many matrix..but nothing defined in efcore

Comment: The best way to understand what is the EF perspective (the DB doesn't matter, all  EFC runtime behaviors are based on the model metadata) is to create a temporary migration. Comment out  `ToSqlQuery`, change `ToTable(null)` with `ToTable("Foo")`, do `Add-Migration`, post the code of the generated migration, do `Remove-Migration` and restore the code.